# before remove object want to do some functionality over its siblings in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

below specified working fine for me but i want to know is there any other best way to do it

```
$(this).parents('form:first')
.siblings('.div-action,.single-field').show()
.siblings('form:first').remove()
```

Like i tried below specified one not helpful

```
$(this).parents('form:first')
.remove(function(){ $('this')
.siblings('.div-action,.single-field').show()});
```

I know below specified way too but i want to know the best way to do this

```
 var temp = $(this).parents('form:first')
temp.siblings('.div-action,.single-field').show()
temp.remove()
```

I want to do it in one line only

Comment: Did you accidentally a word or two here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, one line, with the use of `.end()`:

```
$(this).parents('form:first').siblings('.div-action,.single-field').show().end().remove()
```

Indenting so you can see what I did:

```
  $(this)
    .parents('form:first')
      .siblings('.div-action,.single-field')
        .show()
        .end() // basically ends the selector (siblings) and moves back to previous selector (parent).
    .remove()
```

View the example on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/U6A9h/